# Python / Selenium: am I incorrectly creating and instantiating the class? or is the selenium locator incorrect?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

CONTEXT:

- 1st time asker and long time reader of stack overflow, please let me know of ways if I can improve the question if there are any.
- I am a beginner with both Python and Selenium and am trying to create a simple application while loosely following along this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j7VZsCCnptM as a proof of concept for myself.
- I working with this website https://www.booking.com/ per the tutorial
- At one point in the tutorial, around 1:50:40 the teacher creates a class for storing methods in a more organized manner
- In main.py if we only focus on bot.apply_filters()

[HTML I am locating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm3cM.png)

In the bookingFilters class, I am attempting to locate the above with the bookingFilters.apply_star_rating() and am using the same code in booking.apply_filters()

**THE QUESTION:**
Why am I not finding the element when using

```
filters = BookingFilters(driver=self)
print("Trying the class")
filters.apply_star_rating()
```

But simply using the element locators directly in the booking method works?
Am I instantiating the BookingFilters class incorrectly? I believe I am not because the apply_star_rating() method is printing to the console. Which leads me to believe I am perhaps defining the class incorrectly? or is the premise of creating a class for methods like this naive?

**The console output is**

```
Trying the class
Trying to find element with ('css selector', 'div[data-filters-group="class"]')
============ element with ('css selector', 'div[data-filters-group="class"]') Not Found ============
Trying to find element with ('xpath', '//div[text()="2 stars"]')
============ element with ('xpath', '//div[text()="2 stars"]') Not Found ============
None
====Trying no class====
Trying to find element with ('css selector', 'div[data-filters-group="class"]')
Element found: <div data-filters-group="class" data-testid="filters-group" id="filter_group_class_:R1cq:" class="ffa9856b86 ad9a06523f"><div class="b3d1cacd40 f6b5094aa4"><h3 class="f9afbb0024 f0d4d6a2f5 fda3b74d0d">Star Rating</h3></div><div><div></div></div>........

Trying to find element with ('css selector', '//div[text()="2 stars"]')
============ element with ('css selector', '//div[text()="2 stars"]') Not Found ============
```

**Main.py**

```
import os
import types
import typing
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from booking_package.BookingFilters import BookingFilters
import booking_package.constants as const

def main():
    with Booking() as bot:
        bot.land_first_page()
        bot.select_location(location='Boston')
        bot.select_dates('2023-02-05', '2023-02-08')
        bot.select_occupants_count(4, 0)
        bot.apply_filters()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Booking.py**

```
class Booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=const.CHROME_DRIVER_PATH, teardown=False):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        # keeps the Chrome tab open
        options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += driver_path
        super(Booking, self).__init__(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
        # self.maximize_window()

    def apply_filters(self):
        filters = BookingFilters(driver=self)
        print("Trying the class")
        filters.apply_star_rating()

        print("====Trying no class====")
        star_filter_area = self.wait_for_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-filters-group="class"]'))
        star_filter_selection = self.wait_for_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '//div[text()="2 stars"]'))
        print(star_filter_selection)
        if star_filter_area != None:
            star_box = star_filter_area.find_elements(By.XPATH, 'div[data-filters-item*="class]')
            for element in star_box:
                html = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
                print(html)

    def wait_for_clickable(self, locator, timeout=1, poll_frequency=0.05):
        try:
            print(f'Trying to find element with {locator}')
            element_found = WebDriverWait(self, timeout=timeout, poll_frequency=poll_frequency) \
                .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))
            element_html = element_found.get_attribute('outerHTML')
            if element_found:
                print(f'Element found: {element_html}\n')
            return element_found
        except:
            print(f'============ element with {locator} Not Found ============\n')
            return None
```

**bookingFilters.py**

```
class BookingFilters:
    def __init__(self, driver:WebDriver):
        self.driver = driver

    def apply_star_rating(self):
        star_filter_area = self.wait_for_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-filters-group="class"]'))
        star_filter_selection = self.wait_for_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[text()="2 stars"]'))
        print (star_filter_selection)
        if star_filter_area != None:
            star_box = star_filter_area.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-filters-item*="class]')
            for element in star_box:
                html = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
                print(html)

    def wait_for_clickable(self, locator, timeout=1, poll_frequency=0.05):
        try:
            print(f'Trying to find element with {locator}')
            element_found = WebDriverWait(self, timeout=timeout, poll_frequency=poll_frequency) \
                .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))
            element_html = element_found.get_attribute('outerHTML')
            if element_found:
                print(f'Element found: {element_html}\n')
            return element_found
        except:
            print(f'============ element with {locator} Not Found ============\n')
            return None
```

Comment: What does the teacher explains at _`1:50:40`_ while creating the class?

Comment: The teacher goes over the concept of adding a class to organize the code further. He creates a new file, and defines the class name and its __init__(self, driver) and briefly goes over pramater Typing to allow for code suggestions. He then creates a method for the new class. He returns to the original booking class, imports the new class, instantiates the new class while passing the webdriver as an argument, and demonstrates the working code.

Answer (score 0):

[Correct imports with project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCJGG.png)

I was incorrectly importing the class.

Before Incorrect:
from booking_package.BookingFilters import BookingFilters

After Correct
from .BookingFilters import BookingFilters

Hilariously long post for a missing .

Edit:
in the BookingFilters class
the wait_for_clickable method needed to be given the chrome driver as well, which wasn't being provided

**Before**

```
def wait_for_clickable(self, locator, timeout=1, poll_frequency=0.05):
        try:
            print(f'Trying to find element with {locator}')
            element_found = WebDriverWait(self, timeout=timeout, poll_frequency=poll_frequency) \
                .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))
            element_html = element_found.get_attribute('outerHTML')
            if element_found:
                print(f'Element found: {element_html}\n')
            return element_found
        except:
            print(f'============ element with {locator} Not Found ============\n')
            return None
```

**After**

```
    def wait_for_clickable(self, locator, timeout=1, poll_frequency=0.05):
        try:
            print(f'Trying to find element with {locator}')

            # This line changed self to self.driver
            element_found = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout=timeout, poll_frequency=poll_frequency) \
                .until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator))


            if element_found:
                print(f'Element found\n')
            return element_found
        except:
            print(f'============ element with {locator} Not Found ============\n')
            return None
```